# VS Code - Error check missing in some projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I made a new solution in .NET with a class library (`dotnet new classlib`) and an XUnit test project (`dotnet new xunit`). I then added a reference to the class library, from the test project (`dotnet add <test-project> reference <class-library>`).

Now I have live error checking (syntax highlighting) in the class library, but no in the test project. You can see an example below, where the class `Foo` doesn't exist anywhere, but doesn't generate a live warning in the unit test project (it still fails on build).

This is a VS Code issue only. If I open it in Visual Studio 2022, it works just fine.

What's going on here?

[image: Screenshot from VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer on Twitter](https://twitter.com/lettucemode/status/1572931192416243712) I found a way to fix it...

I had to restart OmniSharp (the C# extension for VS Code). It can be done in the command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). Search for "OmniSharp" and select "OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp".

[image: Restart OmniSharp from the command palette in VS Code.]